# Does there exist random variables such that any strict subset of $\{ X_1, X_2, ... X_n\}$ is independent but $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ are not independent?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let $n$ be any positive integer larger than $1$. 
I want to construct random variables $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$such that any strict subset of $\{ X_1, X_2, ... X_n\}$ is independent but $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ are not independent. 
Any hints or reference are appreciated.

Comment: The case $n=2$ is trivial.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $X_1$, ... , $X_{n-1}$ be i.i.d random variable taking values in $\lbrace -1, 1 \rbrace$ uniformly and let $$X_n = \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} X_i$$
Clearly they are not independent but if you take any subset of those of size at most $n-1$, they are independent:

Let $A\subsetneq \lbrace 1, \dots , n\rbrace$, if $n\notin A$ then independence is trivial so suppose $n\in A$. In that case there is $i\in[1:n-1]$ such that $i\notin A$ but the distribution of all the variables can be rewritten, by symmetry, as $\lbrace X_j \rbrace_{j\neq i}$ are i.i.d random variable uniformly distributed in $\lbrace -1, 1 \rbrace$ and $X_i=\prod\limits_{j\neq i} X_j$ and so the subset is independent.

Comment: Slight quibble.  If the values are in $\{-1,1\}$ rather than $\{0,1\}$ they are not Bernoulli.  If you wish, $X_j = 2 Y_j - 1$ where $Y_j$ is Bernoulli.

Comment: Thank you, I just edited.

Comment: You could use the term Rademacher.

Comment: I guess something is not clear here.. How $X_i$ takes values in $\{-1,1\}$ and later you say it takes values in $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: @Shashi Thank you, it should be fixed now

Comment: What's the most efficient way to conclude that $X_1, X_2, X_3 , \cdots, X_n$ are not indpendent?

Comment: $X_n$ is a function of $X_1,\dots,X_{n-1}$, therefore can be independent of them only if it is a constant, which it is not.